# Arabic txt files and "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, arabic, arabic-support

I have been using this script to compile a list of txt files into a dataframe.

```
#get path of txt file
filePath = []
for file in os.listdir("./arabic_txt"):
    filePath.append(os.path.join("./arabic_txt", file))

#pull file name from text file with regex, capturing the text before the .txt   
fileName = re.compile('\\\\(.*)\.txt')

#make empty dict Data with the key as the file name, and the value as the words in the file.
data = {}
for file in filePath:
    #capturing file name
    key = fileName.search(file)
    with open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as readFile:
        # note that key[1] is the capture group from our search, and that the text is put into a list.
        data[key[1]] = [readFile.read()]

#make dataframe from dict, and rename columns.
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'document', 0:'text'})
```

The code works perfectly on text files containing English text, but somehow it does not work with files containing Arabic text. When I run it on Arabic files, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [99], in <cell line: 11>()
     13     key = fileName.search(file)
     14     with open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as readFile:
     15         # note that key[1] is the capture group from our search, and that the text is put into a list.
---> 16         data[key[1]] = [readFile.read()]
     18 #make dataframe from dict, and rename columns.
     19 df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'document', 0:'text'})

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I check the individual files, and they all seem to be formatted properly in utf-8. I am a bit lost at this point. Please, let me know if you have any feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Can the problem be reduced to `fileName.search(file)` returning `None`? If that is the case, I believe you could improve your question by providing examples of elements of `filePath`.

Comment: Maybe you don't need a regular expression and you could just use [os.path.basename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename).

Comment: @Hernan 

When I print "key" I obtain one "None" and then a series of lines as:
<re.Match object; span=(12, 80), match='filename>

Comment: When I print print(key) for the english files, I do not get "none".

Comment: @Hernán Alarcón
Here are examples of filenames: jo%a%2013%government_work_plan_2013-2016%cabinet%development.txt
jo%a%2021%a_plan_towards_a_secure_summer%cabinet%security.txt